# SDK not comes bundled with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Latest version of Android studio from Google.Not getting Android SDK Component Once I Click on .exe file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just automatically installed with Android Studio now. After installing go to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android and there should one folder called sdk. If not you can install the SDK manually.

Comment: I have installed,But sdk folder is empty.I'm getting "Unable to access Android SDK add-on list" If i try to open android studio.

Comment: Are you somehow blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Okay, try opening Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> Edit (next to the SDK Location field) and you will hopefully be able to install the SDK from there.

Comment: @Christopher,Yeah,Firewall is ON.I don't have permission to Turn OFF Firewall Settings.

Comment: @junior-senior, Android-SDK checkbox is disabled by default

Comment: @kavie, click next at the bottom, it should allow you to install the SDK from there, if not back on the screen where you clicked 'Edit' can you select Android SDK build-Tools and Android SDK Platform -Tools, then apply and that should installed the selected components.

Comment: @junior-senior,Proxy Setting is blocking installation of SDK Components.